# How to pause an AHK or Autohotkey script with one key, but use a different key to unpause it

Tags: autohotkey

I need to pause my AHK or Autohotkey script with the space key, but unpause it with the y key.

I've been searching for a while without any success.
I've tried different combinations, but I never get any of them to work properly.

All I need is to use a different key to unpause an AHK script, than the one used to pause it.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello @user3419297, I hope you can help me this issue, as you have done before.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
Space::
Pause, On
 return

y::
Pause, Off
 return
```